# Separate grouped items in an Excel column

Tags: excel, function

I have a long list of data structured in a column in the following way:

```
miR-4782-5p
miR-4740-3p
miR-3173-5p
miR-617/2340
miR-1260/1260b/1391
miR-4642
miR-1392
```

I need to convert it to the following format:

```
miR-4782-5p
miR-4740-3p
miR-3173-5p
miR-617
miR-2340
miR-1260
miR-1260b
miR-1391
miR-4942
miR-1392
```

Essentially, I just want to separate the data grouped by parentheses, and make it it's own item while continuing down the list.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Visual Basic, so I haven't tried anything on that front.

However, I did write a function which uses two columns and separates the items in an inefficient way as I still need to create new rows after each set.

Comment: If using functions is not convenient enough then I think you will need to use VBA.

Comment: is using of helper columns acceptable?

Comment: Yes, however if there's a way to do it without them it would be favourable.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do just what you need

```
Sub SplitCellsAndExtend_Olddasgf()
'takes cells with inside line feeds and creates new row for each.
'reverses merge into top cell.

Dim strCell As String, lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, sPrefix As String
Const sSplitOn As String = "/"

application.ScreenUpdating = False
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        strCell = Cells(i, 1)
        j = 0

        Do While InStr(1, strCell, sSplitOn) > 0
            Rows(i + j + 1).Insert
            sPrefix = Left(strCell, InStr(strCell, "-"))
            strCell = Right(strCell, Len(strCell) - InStr(1, strCell, sSplitOn))
            Cells(i + j, 1) = Left(Cells(i + j, 1).Value, InStr(1, Cells(i + j, 1), sSplitOn) - 1)
            strCell = sPrefix & strCell
            Cells(i + j + 1, 1).Value = strCell
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    Next
application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to run?

Comment: Works on column A of the active sheet, is that how you're running it? You copy it in a macro module, and run it with F5 from the Editor or Alt+F8 from the worksheet.